# Does not work jQuery defender in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Does not work jQuery defender in IE9. What is wrong?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

var promise_url_1 = $.get('http://test.loc/1.html');
var promise_url_2 = $.get('http://test.loc/2.html');
$.when(promise_url_1, promise_url_2).done(function(promis1, promis2) {
        console.log('yes');
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('error');
    });
};
```

Comment: Post a "working" example. http://jsbin.com/ http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The second URL looks wrong - missing a dot before `html`. Maybe the first one is successful while the second is failing? Add an `always` and check the responses.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fhns3w5m/

Comment: What is a "*jQuery defender*"?

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong?

You haven't put your script in a `<script>`. And also it's got a closing parenthesis too many:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var promise_url_1 = $.get('http://test.loc/1.html');
    var promise_url_2 = $.get('http://test.loc/2.html');
    $.when(promise_url_1, promise_url_2).done(function(promis1, promis2) {
        console.log('yes');
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('error');
    });
// }; <--
</script>
```